# perfmon asks me for NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM credentials

Tags: windows-10, perfmon

I have setup my own performance counter data collector. It was running for a while and now I want to edit it. Upon clicking OK it asks me to enter credentials for NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM! WTH? Obviously I don't know these and I don't think there even is any password!
[image]

I can create new data collector set but any time I try to edit some it asks me for this and I can't save the changes.

EDIT:
I am talking about my work laptop with Windows 10 Enterprise build 1903. I am using it as any other person - having AzureAD account which is also member of local administrators group.
My home pc where I noticed the same behavior is Windows 10 Pro build 1903. There I am logged on with a local user account which is member of Administrators group.

Comment: Please add to your question what version of Windows you're running.  Are you using a domain account and is your user apart of the `Administrators` group?  _(`SYSTEM`, as you likely know, has no credentials)_

Comment: Question edited. And yes, I DID say that I don't think there even is any password for system, so that's why I think this behavior is really weird! Don't you agree?

Comment: Are you running perfmon from the Task Scheduler?

Comment: you mean start the collector set via scheduled task? No. I just click start, type perfmon and there I can create collector sets, but any time I edit them it prompts me like that

Comment: What I have found:
1. This behavior appeared after kb4525236
2. Both logman and perfmon by default create a data collector set with "NT AUTHORITY/SYSTEM" account, but when, as you suggested, you remove username and password it changes to "SYSTEM"

Answer (score 6):

So I don't know what causes it but seems like I found a solution/workaround: whenever it asks me for those credentials, I just delete the value from login and submit empty values and this works...

Comment: it happened on my other PC as well! Please test and tell me if you notice the same behavior. Maybe some recent patch caused it

Comment: Just to remark that NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM *has no password*.

Comment: haha, yes, windows! Delete the user name entirely.

Answer (score 1):

I remark that NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM *has no password*, so an empty password is the
correct entry for that prompt.

I can only conjuncture that your domain account ended up not being member of the
local groups of Performance Log Users and/or Performance Monitor Users,
so probably is not a full local Administrator.

These groups are defined as:

- **Performance Log Users**
  Members of this group can manage performance counters, logs, and alerts on a computer — both locally and from remote clients — without being a member of the Administrators group.
- **Performance Monitor Users**
  Members of this group can monitor performance counters on a computer — locally and from remote clients — without being a member of the Administrators group or the Performance Log Users groups.

This same problem was discussed in the post
[Permissions Issue with Files Generated by PerfMon](https://serverfault.com/questions/452281/permissions-issue-with-files-generated-by-perfmon),
where it was said:

> Data Collector Sets can contain sensitive information about the computer, so access to them typically requires the user at least be a member of the Performance Log Users group.

The solution there, actually a workaround, was to create a scheduled task that
will fire when the Data Collector Set finishes running,
to modify the ACLs of the directory structure recursively to "Everyone Full Control".

There was a problem with creating a trigger for the job, which then required
a Custom trigger entered manually as XML:

```
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational">
    <Select Path="Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational">
        *[System[TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) &lt;= 3600000]]]
         and
        *[System[(EventID='102')]]
         and
        *[EventData[Data and (Data='YOUR DATA COLLECTOR SET NAME')]] 
    </Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

The trigger launched this PowerShell script:

```
$Path = "C:\PerfLogs\Admin\New Data Collector Set"
$ACL  = (Get-Item $Path).GetAccessControl("Access")
$ACE  = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("Everyone", "FullControl", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
$ACL.AddAccessRule($ACE)
ForEach($_ In Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse)
{
    Set-Acl -ACLObject $ACL $_.FullName
}
```

This solution is complicated, so it might be simpler to just continue
entering an empty password when prompted.

Comment: actually I cannot submit it with empty password. If I do it says wrong password. I have to delete the login as well and only that way it works - to submit both fields empty. Do you confirm that if you open properties of a collector set, change the interval value for example and click OK then it saves without questions?

Comment: I can't confirm it, since I'm not in a position to duplicate the problem.

Comment: what position do you mean? Do you have a windows 10 computer? That's all you need to test this